# Redirection from Observer is throwing a FATAL Error

Tags: magento-enterprise, redirect

In my event Observer.php class I am using the following code, but it is throwing me a Fatal Error.

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getFrontNameByRoute() on a non-object in /var/www/tweak/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php on line 216`

I am using the following code for redirection

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl()."us/");
```

I have also tried it with some hardcoded URLs for but same problem. I remember it was working earlier.

I am using `PHP Version 5.4.34-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1`

Comment: trace the object then and why it is not existing , maybe  in your observer request all parts needed for this to work are not initiated.

Comment: Hi Anton, any light on how I can trace the object? I am using commerceBug2 extension in case if that will be of any help for tracing?

Comment: grep '>getFrontNameByRoute' app -rsn see where it is called and see what it needs to set the object then you can say why it is not set

Comment: What's the code @ `/var/www/tweak/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php` on line 216. 

On CE 1.9.0.2 it's 

`} elseif ($this->getRouter('admin')->getFrontNameByRoute($routeName)) {`

and you should be asking why getRouter('admin') is returning false

Comment: Yes, its the same code Richard! its the same code `} elseif ($this->getRouter('admin')->getFrontNameByRoute($routeName)) {` for me in my Magento EE 1.13, about the error, thats what the PHP prompts, but you are right `$this->getRouter('admin')` is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find that you need to send the response and then exit in the observer to avoid such errors. You could try the following snippet.

```
$response = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse();
$response->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl()."us/");
$response->sendResponse();
exit();
```